# Adding commas in between JSON objects while writing,

Tags: python, json, file, io, ijson

I am parsing an extremely large JSON file using IJSON and then writing the contents to a temp file. Afterwards, I overwrite the original file with the contents of the temp file.

```
FILE_NAME = 'file-name'
DIR_PATH = 'path'

#Generator function that yields dictionary objects.
def constructDictionary():
    data = open(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, FILE_NAME + ".json"), "rb")
    row = ijson.items(data,'item')
    for record in row:
        yield record
    data.close()

def writeToTemp(row, temp):
    #Needs to add a comma
    json.dump(row, temp)

def writeTempToFile(temp):
    temp.seek(0)
    data = open(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, FILE_NAME + ".json"), "wb")
    data.write(b'[')
    for line in temp:
        data.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
    data.write(b']')
    data.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'r+')
    for row in constructDictionary():
        writeToTemp(row,temp)
    writeTempToFile(temp)
    temp.close()
```

My issue is that I end up with the JSON objects being written without commas between them. I can't parse over the file again and add the missing commas as it would take way too long. Ideally, while writing i would be able to add a comma at the end of each json.dump(). But, how would i handle the final entry?

Some way to determine when the generator function has reached the end of the file? Then i would use a flag or pass a variable so that it wouldn't write the final comma.

Or, i could use file.seek() to go to the character before the final character and remove it. But that sounds not good.

I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ideally, while writing i would be able to add a comma at the end of each json.dump(). But, how would i handle the final entry?*

I suggest taking different view - rather than writing comma after each but last element, writing comma before each but first element. This way it is enough to `next` once before using generator normal way, consider following simple example: I want to print 10 times `A` sheared by `*`, then I can do:

```
import itertools
a10 = itertools.repeat("A", 10)
print(next(a10), end='')
for i in a10:
    print('*', end='')
    print(i, end='')
```

output:

```
A*A*A*A*A*A*A*A*A*A
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this json.dump(row, temp, indent=4)